# O(log n) time complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

The function `power(n, p)` that takes a number and a power and returns the number raised to the given power.
this function must have a complexity of O(log(p)).

```
def power(n,p):

    if (p == 0): return 1
    elif (int(p % 2) == 0):
        return (power(n, int(p / 2)) *
               power(n, int(p / 2)))
    else:
        return (n * power(n, int(p / 2)) *
                   power(n, int(p / 2)))
print(power(2,8))
```

does this satisfy the o(log n ) complexity. i dont really understand how the log n complexity works

Comment: *i dont really understand how the log n complexity works* Did you try to figure out how *log n complexity works*?

Comment: @AshvinSharma not really. would you mind explaining a bit ?

Comment: Not really. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to make efforts in learning something.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation for your code is:

```
T(p) = 2 * T(p / 2) + O(1)
```

Using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), we get `T(p) = O(p)`. So, it is not `O(log(p))`.

---

To make it `O(log(p))`, you can do:

```
def power(n, p):
    if p == 0:
        return 1

    # Call this only once, instead of two times.
    power_p_divided_by_2 = power(n, p // 2)

    if p % 2:
        return n * power_p_divided_by_2 * power_p_divided_by_2
    else:
        return power_p_divided_by_2 * power_p_divided_by_2

print(power(2, 8))
```

The recurrence relation for this code is:

```
T(p) = T(p / 2) + O(1)
```

Using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), we get T(p) = O(log(p)).